# How to detect the compression level of a PNG file?

Tags: image, png

Services like Google PageSpeed tell me that I can save file space, by compressing PNG files. I haven't found a (Linux) tool that would give me such information, unless I actually compress the file.

Is there a (fast) way to detect the compression level of a PNG file, without actually compressing it? Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

If you have pngcheck, which is available [here](http://png-mng.sourceforge.net/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html), you can run

```
pngcheck -v file.png | grep zlib
```

That will tell you the level of compression that was used (superfast, fast, default, or maximum).  But there's really no way to tell if the PNG filter selection was optimized other than running a compressor and checking the resulting size.

The question about what Google Pagespeed Service actually did is moot now because the service has been (or is being) [discontinued](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/page-speed-service-discuss/h4jyUpv6Bc8). From the Pagespeed [source code](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/psol), which is open source under the Apache-2.0 license, it appears that it can be configured to try various compression methods and compare the resulting filesize to the original filesize.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Do you have an idea how Google PageSpeed can so quickly give me the feedback that my PNG ist not fully compressed? Do you think they compress each file (on fast servers) or might they have their own tool to do so?